# regular expression attempts to match all versions of foo older than 1.2.3

Tags: regex

I want to match all versions greater than 1.2.3 , so 
`foo 1\.([0-1]\.|2\.[0-3])` , will not work obviously.

Comment: I would try to avoid using regex for this. What language are you working in?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are three parts:

1. Greater than 1:

   ```
   [2-9]
   ```
2. Greater than 1.2:

   ```
   1\.[3-9]
   ```
3. Greater than 1.2.3:

   ```
   1\.2\.[4-9]
   ```

Combine them:

```
(?<=\s|^)([2-9]|1\.[3-9]|1\.2\.[4-9])
```

This assumes single-digit versions, though. For multi-digit versions you could use:

```
(?<=\s|^)([2-9]|1\d|1\.[3-9]|1\.\d{2}|1\.2\.[4-9]|1\.2\.\d{2})
```

Comment: @Joey you have to thionk of these versions as Something like software versions of application, where they can takevalues 1.2.4, 1.3.5, and so on

Comment: Huh? I do. But there is no point asserting anything about the following digits if you already know the version is greater.

Comment: how about 1.21.3 ? it dind't match

Comment: It should be matched by the `1\.\d{2}` branch.

Comment: Should ... but seems not ... (test with the url that i include into my answer)

Comment: Don, sorry; I introduced an error when trying to adapt it to version numbers anywhere within a string. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something greater than 1.2.3, then you only need to check each digit if the previous digit is equal:

```
foo 1\.(2\.[4-9]|[3-9]\.\d)|[2-9]\.\d\.\d
```

If we assume multi-digit versions, then you would have to use something like

```
foo 1\.(2\.([4-9]|\d{2,})|([3-9]|\d{2,})\.\d+)|([2-9]|\d{2,})\.\d+\.\d+
```

Comment: For your multi-digit version, you should replace the simple occurrences of `\d` (those not followed by `{2,}` with `d+`.  Otherwise you won't match eg `"18.28.92"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to generate matches based on what a number *means* semantically. Regular expressions are only good at validating *syntax*, not *semantics*. While you can technically write a regular expression to accomplish your goal (Joey's will work), it will be more of a hack than a good design.

Try parsing the pieces of the version string into integers and then comparing them mathematically. For example, in C#:

```
public bool IsV1Bigger() {
    string v1 = "1.3.2";
    string v2 = "1.2.3";

    if(v1 == v2) return false;

    string[] v1Array = v1.Split('.');
    string[] v2Array = v2.Split('.');

    if(Convert.ToInt32(v1Array[0]) < Convert.ToInt32(v2Array[0])) return false;
    else if(Convert.ToInt32(v1Array[0]) > Convert.ToInt32(v2Array[0])) return true;

    if(Convert.ToInt32(v1Array[1]) < Convert.ToInt32(v2Array[1])) return false;
    else if(Convert.ToInt32(v1Array[1]) > Convert.ToInt32(v2Array[1])) return true;

    if(Convert.ToInt32(v1Array[2]) < Convert.ToInt32(v2Array[2])) return false;
    else if(Convert.ToInt32(v1Array[2]) > Convert.ToInt32(v2Array[2])) return true;
}
```

Comment: In Python you could do this with: `if tuple(int(x) for x in v1.split('.')) > (1,2,3): ...`

Comment: I forgot to add brackets to my array declarations. Trying to write while talking on the phone is a bad idea. Fixing it now.

Comment: C# is almost always more verbose than Python -- Python is great at condensing logic. There is probably a one-liner using LINQ to do this but I'd rather not think too hard about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foo [1-9]*\.((([3-9]{1}[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)|([2]{1}[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]*))|([2-9]{1}[0-9]*\.([3-9]{1}[0-9}{1})|([4-9]{1}[0-9]*)))
```

Isn't compact, but do the job

You can use [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#intro) to try

Comment: i tried but this does not even seem to work for 1.2.4, am i missing something?

Comment: @kamal: you're right, i just forget about it... one moment, i'll update

Comment: did you test it against 1.2.4 ? unless my regex tester is unique, i am using regExhibit on Mac, to verify

Comment: Yes, I tested it with mine and .. funny, it dind't work.. But i break this into parts and put the whole thing again into that site ... I can't understand where did i've made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a complicated regular expression for this I would extract the individual numbers *a*, *b* and *c* with a regular expression like (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) and use an expression like (*a* > 1) || (*b* > 2) || (*c* > 3) to do the comparison, where || is a short-circuit OR operator.

Comment: @DonCallisto: You are right, thanks. I updated my answer to reflect this.